# Route between multiple markers

Tags: google-maps, matrix, google-api

Is it possible to plot multiple markers as well show routes between these and origin? For example: I have one origin and four different destinations. I want the routes to be shown between the origin and the destinations, so that it is A to B, A to C, A to D, A to E. Can this be done? I have only seen the option to display the route between two points or to calculate distance between multiple. I want to be able to calculate the distance as well as showing the route on the map.

So far this is what my code looks like:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {

  var values = $("#street").val();

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = values;

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    } 

    service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(48.856614, 2.352222);
    var destinationb = new google.maps.LatLng(41.385064, 2.173403);
    var destinationc = new google.maps.LatLng(44.584910, 5.133122);
    var destinationd = new google.maps.LatLng(45.365187, 0.647394);
    var destinationIcon = 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2278%22%20height%3D%2238%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2038%2038%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23333333%22%20stroke%3D%22%23ccc%22%20stroke-width%3D%22.5%22%20d%3D%22M34.305%2016.234c0%208.83-15.148%2019.158-15.148%2019.158S3.507%2025.065%203.507%2016.1c0-8.505%206.894-14.304%2015.4-14.304%208.504%200%2015.398%205.933%2015.398%2014.438z%22%2F%3E%3Ctext%20transform%3D%22translate(19%2018.5)%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%20style%3D%22font-family%3A%20Arial%2C%20sans-serif%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3B%22%20font-size%3D%2212%22%20text-anchor%3D%22middle%22%3E' + "" + '%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E';
    var originIcon = 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2238%22%20height%3D%2238%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2038%2038%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23808880%22%20stroke%3D%22%23ccc%22%20stroke-width%3D%22.5%22%20d%3D%22M34.305%2016.234c0%208.83-15.148%2019.158-15.148%2019.158S3.507%2025.065%203.507%2016.1c0-8.505%206.894-14.304%2015.4-14.304%208.504%200%2015.398%205.933%2015.398%2014.438z%22%2F%3E%3Ctext%20transform%3D%22translate%2819%2018.5%29%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%20style%3D%22font-family%3A%20Arial%2C%20sans-serif%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3B%22%20font-size%3D%2212%22%20text-anchor%3D%22middle%22%3E' + "" + '%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [origin],
            destinations: [destination, destinationb, destinationc, destinationd],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, 
        callback
    );   

    function callback(response, status) {

        if(status=="OK") {
            var originList = response.originAddresses;
            var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;
            var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');

           var showGeocodedAddressOnMap = function(distance, asDestination) {
              var icon = asDestination ? destinationIcon : originIcon;
              return function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                  map.fitBounds(bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location));
                  var markersArray = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    icon: icon
                  });

                  google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray, 'click', function (evt) {
                    infowindow.setContent('<strong>Avstånd:</strong> ' + distance);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                  });



                } else {
                  alert('Geocode was not successful due to: ' + status);
                }
              };
            };            

        for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
              var results = response.rows[i].elements;
              geocoder.geocode({'address': originList[i]},
                  showGeocodedAddressOnMap(results[i].distance.text, false));
              for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                geocoder.geocode({'address': destinationList[j]}, showGeocodedAddressOnMap(results[j].distance.text, true));

                outputDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
                    ': ' + results[j].distance.text + '<br>';



              }
            }

        } else {
            alert("Error: " + status);
        }
    }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          showTooltip: true,
          showInfoWindow: true
        });



  }); 

});


</script>
<div id="output"></div>
<p></p>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Yes it can be done.  What does your existing code look like?

Comment: @geocodezip I have updated my question with my current progress. I am not sure how to implement the routes, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip I have gone through that documentation before and I can't find anything relating to displaying multiple routes at the same time. Therefor I can't provide you with a better coding example, since I am unsure of where to start.

Comment: I contains an example of how to implement **a** route.  You need to do that multiple times for more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the routes, call the directions service.  Modified function from the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions):

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, map) {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

calculateAndDisplayRoute(origin, destination, map);
calculateAndDisplayRoute(origin, destinationb, map);
calculateAndDisplayRoute(origin, destinationc, map);
calculateAndDisplayRoute(origin, destinationd, map);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/p5tycgds/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, map) {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  showTooltip: true,
  showInfoWindow: true
});
var values = $("#street").val();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = values;
geocoder.geocode({
  'address': address
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
  }
  service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(48.856614, 2.352222);
  var destinationb = new google.maps.LatLng(41.385064, 2.173403);
  var destinationc = new google.maps.LatLng(44.584910, 5.133122);
  var destinationd = new google.maps.LatLng(45.365187, 0.647394);
  var destinationIcon = 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2278%22%20height%3D%2238%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2038%2038%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23333333%22%20stroke%3D%22%23ccc%22%20stroke-width%3D%22.5%22%20d%3D%22M34.305%2016.234c0%208.83-15.148%2019.158-15.148%2019.158S3.507%2025.065%203.507%2016.1c0-8.505%206.894-14.304%2015.4-14.304%208.504%200%2015.398%205.933%2015.398%2014.438z%22%2F%3E%3Ctext%20transform%3D%22translate(19%2018.5)%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%20style%3D%22font-family%3A%20Arial%2C%20sans-serif%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3B%22%20font-size%3D%2212%22%20text-anchor%3D%22middle%22%3E' + "" + '%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E';
  var originIcon = 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2238%22%20height%3D%2238%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2038%2038%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23808880%22%20stroke%3D%22%23ccc%22%20stroke-width%3D%22.5%22%20d%3D%22M34.305%2016.234c0%208.83-15.148%2019.158-15.148%2019.158S3.507%2025.065%203.507%2016.1c0-8.505%206.894-14.304%2015.4-14.304%208.504%200%2015.398%205.933%2015.398%2014.438z%22%2F%3E%3Ctext%20transform%3D%22translate%2819%2018.5%29%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%20style%3D%22font-family%3A%20Arial%2C%20sans-serif%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3B%22%20font-size%3D%2212%22%20text-anchor%3D%22middle%22%3E' + "" + '%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E';
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(origin, destination, map);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(origin, destinationb, map);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(origin, destinationc, map);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(origin, destinationd, map);

  service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination, destinationb, destinationc, destinationd],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    },
    callback
  );

  function callback(response, status) {
    if (status == "OK") {
      var originList = response.originAddresses;
      var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');

      var showGeocodedAddressOnMap = function(distance, asDestination) {
        var icon = asDestination ? destinationIcon : originIcon;
        return function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            map.fitBounds(bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location));
            var markersArray = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
              icon: icon
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray, 'click', function(evt) {
              if (asDestination) {
                infowindow.setContent('<strong>Avstånd:</strong> ' + distance);
              } else {
                infowindow.setContent('<strong>Origin</strong> ');
              }
              infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful due to: ' + status);
          }
        };
      };

      for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
        var text;
        if (results[i].status != "OK") {
          text = results[i].status;
        } else {
          results[i].distance.text;
        }
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': originList[i]
          },
          showGeocodedAddressOnMap(text, false));
        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
          console.log("j=" + j + " destinationList[" + j + "]=" + destinationList[j] + " results[" + j + "]=" + results[j]);
          geocoder.geocode({
            'address': destinationList[j]
          }, showGeocodedAddressOnMap(results[j].distance.text, true));
          outputDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
            ': ' + results[j].distance.text + '<br>';
        }
      }
    } else {
      alert("Error: " + status);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
<input id="street" value="Orléans, France" />
<input id="submit" type="button" value="click" />
<p></p>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Didn't expect a full example, just a nudge in the right way. So thank you.